# Problem in the change of line when reading files in C

Tags: c, fgetc, pgm

I'm reading a .pgm file (like the lines below) with "fgetc(file)". When getting only the numbers with a loop in which I avoid the spaces in between (it seems it treats each space, no matter how big it is, as a single character),  it joints the last number of a line and the first one from the following line (ex, 146 last number and 105 first number, it gives 146105).

```
113 116 97  124 146
105 100 112 98  88
100 117 98  87  126
131 101 87  137 161
```

When simply printing the contents of the file, I get a lot of spaces on the change of line in the console, like this:

```
113     116     97      124     146                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
105
```

When printing the contents, each character on a single line, i get this other output:

```
9
7
    //one line
1
2
4
    //one line
1
4
6
    //change of linne in the file, two lines here!!!!

1
0
5
    //one line
1
0
0
```

Any ideas about how I should treat this part of the file?
Here is my code:

```
int get_number(int current[4], int n)
{
    int final_number, index = 0, max = n;
    while (index < max)
    {
        final_number += current[index] * pow(10, (n-1));
        index++;
        n --;
    }
    return final_number;
}

file = fopen("baboon.pgm", "r");
int info = fgetc(file), n;

while (info != EOF)
{
        n = 0;
        while (info != '    ' || info != '  ' || info != '  ' || info != '  ')
        {
                printf("%c", info);
                int current_number[4];
                n++;
        }
        if (current_number[0] != 0)
        {
                printf("%d ", get_number(current_number, n));
        }
        info = fgetc(file);
}
```

I think that with this piece of the code you can get an idea. If need more, say it. I also leave you here a link to download the image file if you want: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZYIU6fcUOnhRND2zph5MUr8545P6U8bX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Show the code as a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help find problems in something we can't see.

Comment: When you go to the doctor, don't just say "ouch!"

Comment: `info != '    ' || info != '  ' || info != '  ' || info != '  ')` is certainly wrong.  If `info` is a space character, then it's not a tab and the condition is true.  If `info` is a tab, then it's not a space and the condition is true.  IOw `while(info != '    ' || info != '  ' || info != '  ' || info != '  ')` is equivalent to `while(1)`